# MVC Session id loading data from database of users with a different id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, session, model-view-controller

I have developed a career application page using MVC and EF where the user when loading the page gets a random unique id to which I add some extra numbers and then assign(?) it to a session id variable like below:

```
        var uniqueID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var tempcount = (db.Applicants.Select(x => x)).Count();
        user.FormId = tempcount + "_" + uniqueID;
        Session["id"] = user.FormId;
```

Scrolling down the form the user must complete tables that include previous work experience, qualifications etc.

To load data on each for the specific user I do the following:

```
        public ActionResult GetData(Applicant applicant)
        {
           
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var tosee = (string)Session["id"];
            IEnumerable<WorkExp> workexpList = db.WorkExps.Where(x => x.FormId == tosee).ToList();
            
            return Json(new { data = workexpList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

For each table there is a similar method like the above.

Every once in a few months I receive complaints from users telling me they can see the data of other random applicants!

Can someone explain me why could this be happening?

Comment: Does your data model has explicit relation between Applicant and WorkExp entities?

Comment: Yes. The FormId of the applicant is FK to WorkExp

Comment: Why don't you use FormId from Applicant to filter data since you are passing applicant?